# Next tuesday, not AFTER this tuesday

Tags: php, datetime, time, strtotime

How do I (in an elegant way) get strtotime to select the first upcoming tuesday, **and use today if today is tuesday**?

I first used

```
strtotime('next Tuesday');
```

Then the clock passed midnight monday and strtotime began targeting the NEXT tuesday

```
strtotime('next Tuesday', strtotime('tomorrow'))
```

does not seem to change anything (still targets the tuesday next week)

```
strtotime('this tuesday')
```

works today, but which tuesday will it target tomorrow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strtotime("this tuesday")` is what you're looking for

```
//given current datetime of Tue Jul  8 03:40:27
print date('Y-m-d',strtotime('this tuesday')); //2014-07-08
print date('Y-m-d',strtotime('this monday')); //2014-07-14
print date('Y-m-d',strtotime('this wednesday')); //2014-07-09
```

Comment: And that targets always the COMING tuesday? Or does it also target tuesday YESTERDAY?

Comment: @mowgli it targets the nearest tuesday greater or equal than today. it does not target yesterday. note `this monday` yields `7/14`

Comment: Ok, gonna try it and see what happens tonight at 00:00 ;)

Answer (score 0):

please review this code

```
<?php

 $day=date('D');
if($day=='r'){
    $date=date('Y-m-d');
}else{
    $date=date('Y-m-d',strtotime('next tuesday'));
}
echo $date;
?>
```

Comment: That could work, but I want to avoid if statements if I can just use strtotime('next tuesday', strtotime('yesterday')).. so far it works

Comment: There's nothing wrong with if statements. As you've more than one condition to adhere to, you're going to have to. Maybe you could wrap it in a ternary operator but that's no more preferable to if/else.

Comment: No there's nothing wrong with it. But why do it, if strtotime has a perfect build-in easy solution

Answer (score 0):

One way is to compare this tuesday to today, if it is lower than today so next tuesday is next week :

```
$today = new DateTime("today");
$tuesday = new DateTime("this tuesday");
if($today > $tuesday){
   $tuesday->modify("next tuesday");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can avoid using statement.

```
 <?php 
    $today = date('D');
    $Tuesday= strtotime("Monday"); // change To Monday to test
    $secondTuesday=strtotime("next Tuesday",$Tuesday);
    echo $today === $Tuesday? date('d.m.Y',$secondTuesday):$today ;


  ?>
```

Comment: ternary is hidden if.

Comment: yes, right. But i thought he wanted a bit much neater code

Comment: Thanks, but I was pretty sure strtotime had to have what I needed somewhere, and I wanted to avoid using unnecessary/multiline code for it, if possible. And it did: strtotime("this tuesday")